# WordPress cannot upload data after migration

Tags: uploads, errors, migration, deployment

After migrating a WordPress instance from one hoster to another, it's impossible to upload any media. Uploads fail with the message "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2016/11. Is its parent directory writable by the server?". Also, WordPress tells me that the max file size is 2MB.

I've tried the following already:

- Checking `phpinfo()`. Nothing suspicious there. `phpinfo()` tells me that max file size is 32MB.
- Checking the owner and group for all directories and files.
- Checking the permissions of files and dirctories. Even setting wp-content/uploads temporarily to 777 didn't help.
- Making sure .htaccess is there and correct.
- Creating a php script that creates the new directory manually, bypassing WordPress. Works like a charm. So php must be configured right.
- Installing a fresh copy of WordPress in parallel and trying that version out. That works. Uploading media in the parallel installation works perfectly. Max file size is shown as 32MB.

When trying to upload media a couple of times, actually the directory gets created. However, no media gets uploaded and the error message stays the same. I've tried to upgrade to the newest version of WordPress in place. Strangely, the updater is able to download the newest archive and to extract it. However, it doesn't install.

Also now log file is create when I turn on the debugging options. As a WP noob, I'm pretty much in the dark. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there an wp-content/uploads/2016 directory?  You mentioned you changed the permssion for uploads, make sure that 2016 is set too.  What does the httpd error log say?

Comment: @user42826 Yes, the directory gets created by WordPress after a while. The permissions are set recursively. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the httpd log, as I'm using a hosted web environment. Not having an error log doesn't make things simpler :(

Comment: please give www-data owner to uploads folder and permission of folder as 755

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem, and the issue is resolved.
Follow the steps:

1. Login to database phpmyadmin.
2. Click on your database and find a table with the name "wp_options" and click on it.
   [image]
3. Click on Browse at the right top side.
4. Find "upload_path" and click on pencil icon to edit field.
   [image]
5. Cut the file location path and paste somewhere for safe side.
6. Click on Go for save changes.

**Issue Resolved**
Go to WordPress >Media > add new > upload any file and check.

***I hope your issue resolved with this method.***

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, turns out it's because wordpress uses an upload path from the database which may not have been changed.

1. Find the wp_options table and the upload_path option in particular
2. Change the value of upload_path to your updated upload path

Comment: Thanks @Callombert. You saved me! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, even when I move folder from one subdomain to another on same server, migrated site require to be `Uploads` subfolder at least `775`, on `755` doesn't work, I do know why but `775` helps.

Comment: Same dilemma! Your suggestion of changing the folder permission to 775 did allow my uploads to go through. However, this cannot be safe to leave it at that setting, correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

I had the same problem after a hosting migration: I couldn't upload any image or install/update any plugin.

I've checked my **wp_options** table, but everything was ok (Even *upload_path* value).

All my permissions were also set correctly to *755* and *644* for folders and files.

**Solution:**

It turns out, I uploaded the new Wordpress version using my regular FTP user. Then, this user also will be the owner of the WP installation.

My solution was quite simple (after I realized), just restore the original WP user: **www-data**

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data my_worpdress_folder
```

I hope it helps someone else, next time.

Best regards,
Jesús.